# Transit visa on arrival at Moscow airport

Tags: transit-visas, moscow

I have an 11-hour layover at Moscow airport. Can I get a transit visa at the airport to visit Moscow city? I am an Indian citizen travelling from Delhi to Oslo.

Comment: Transit visa issued to people, who need to transfer through the territory of a country, e.g. from one airport to another. You don't.

Comment: What kind of a transit visa do you need? Do you want to exit the airport?